# A MIPS palindrome

Tags: mips, palindrome, uppercase, lowercase, punctuation

The current code that I have looks as such. It can successfully read if a string is a palindrome when punctuation is not entered.

```c
.data
buffer: .space 80

input:  .asciiz "Enter a string: "
output: .asciiz "Your string: "
paly:   .asciiz "This is a palindrome "
notp:   .asciiz "This is not a palindrome"

.text

main:
    li $v0, 4        # system call code for print_str
    la $a0, input    # address of string to print
    syscall          # print the input

    li $v0, 8        # code for syscall read_string
    la $a0, buffer   # tell syscall where the buffer is
    li $a1, 80       # tell syscall how big the buffer is

    syscall

    la $a0, buffer  # move buffer into a0
    li $v0, 4       # print buffer
    syscall

    la $t1, buffer  # begining of the string
    la $t2, buffer  # end of the string

    li $t0, 0

loop:
    lb   $t3,($t2)  # load the byte of the end of the string
    beqz $t3,endl   # if its equal to 0 then branch out of the loop
    addu $t2, $t2,1 # if in loop the increment to next character
    jal  loop       # repeat the loop

upper:
    addi $t4,$t4,32
    j lowered

lowered:
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    sb   $t4, 0($a0)
    addi $a0,$a0,1
    j loop

endl:
    subu $t2, $t2, 2     # subtracting 2 to move back from \0 and \n

check:
    #lb   $t4, 0($a0)
    #beqz $t4, after
    #beq  $t4, 10,  after
    #slti $t2, $t4, 91
    #li   $t3, 1
    #beq  $t2, $t3, upper

    bge $t1, $t2, palindrome  # if both sides are equal then its a palindrome
                              # call palindrome

    lb $t3, ($t1)             # load the byte into register t3
    lb $t4, ($t2)             # load the end byte into register t4

    bne  $t3, $t4, notpaly    # if the two register bytes are not equal its it not  a palindrome
    addu $t1, $t1, 1          # increment the beginning of the string to next char

    subu $t2, $t2, 1          # decrement end of string to next char to compare
    jal  check                # repeat the loop

palindrome:
    la  $a0, paly   # calling paly from data
    li  $v0, 4      # call for reading string
    syscall
    jal exit        # jump to end

notpaly:
    la  $a0,notp    # calling notp from data
    li  $v0, 4      # call for reading string
    syscall
    jal exit        # jump to end

after:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, output
    syscall

    la $a0, buffer
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

exit:

    li $v0 ,10     # call to end program
    syscall        # call os
```

Now I know I need to implement code such as to make uppercase lowercase, and to remove punctuation.

With my already stored bits in check: I have some commented code, and this would be to to test if a character is uppercase, then jump to the function and lower it by adding 32. But it does not compile correctly and i am assuming this is because I am not storing the bits correctly.

```
#lb   $t4, 0($a0)
#beqz $t4, after
#beq  $t4, 10,  after
#slti $t2, $t4, 91
#li   $t3, 1
#beq  $t2, $t3, upper
```

Comment: Define _"does not compile correctly"_. If you're getting error messages from the assembler then you need to include those in your question.

Comment: When its run it gives a out of range error. Ive messed with the code since posting so cant get the exact same error. But it is caused by me not using load byte and the right registers. Im trying to modify the buffer, but don't know which loop to do it within.

Comment: Ok, compile-time errors and runtime errors are two different things. If you can't reproduce the error anymore then I find it unclear exactly what the question is about.

Comment: NOTE: this code will NOT work correctly on palindromes whose length is odd [e.g. civic] - tested on MARS 4.5