# How to pass an input string from user to a MIPS program

Tags: assembly, mips, palindrome, mars-simulator

I'm trying to solve a problem to write assembly language program to detect if a phrase or characters entered by the user is a
palindrome.

I've gotten this far, and I believe everything should work, but I'm wondering how I can implement this so that it takes an actual word to test.
When I run in MARS, there's simply no input option.

```
.data
string_space: .space 1024
is_palin_msg: .asciiz "The string is a palindrome.\n"
not_palin_msg: .asciiz "The string is not a palindrome.\n"

.text
main: 
la $a0, string_space
li $a1, 1024
li $v0, 8
syscall

la $t1, string_space
la $t2, string_space

length_loop:
lb $t3, ($t2)
beqz $t3, end_length_loop
addu $t2, $t2, 1 
b length_loop

end_length_loop:
subu $t2, $t2, 2

test_loop:
bge $t1, $t2, is_palin

lb $t3, ($t1)
lb $t4, ($t2)
bne $t3, $t4, not_palin

addu $t1, $t1, 1
subu $t2, $t2, 1
b test_loop

is_palin: 
la $a0, is_palin_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall
b exit

not_palin:
la $a0, not_palin_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall
b exit

exit: 
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I've tried

```
string_space: .asciiz "Enter your word:\n"
```

and also

```
string_space: .asciiz "racecar"
```

but I haven't quite been able to get it yet.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - taking also as template this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204116/a-mips-palindrome) [you are strongly invited to check similar questions before posting] - you need to introduce in your code a `.data` section with an `input` string to ask the user to enter the string to check

```
.data
string_space: .space 1024

input:  .asciiz "Enter a string: "
is_palin_msg: .asciiz "The string is a palindrome.\n"
not_palin_msg: .asciiz "The string is not a palindrome.\n"  
# other strings you may need
```

Then you can start setting the logic to push them out

```
.text

main:
    li $v0, 4              # system call code for print_str
    la $a0, input          # address of string to print
    syscall                # print the input

    li $v0, 8              # code for syscall read_string
    la $a0, string_space   # tell syscall where the buffer is
    li $a1, 1024           # tell syscall how big the buffer is
    syscall    

    # double check the buffer content [see the next snippet]

# rest of the code to test
```

You will start asking the user a string [in this case limited to 1024 bytes/characters]. Reading the `"System Calls and I/O"` section of [this link](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm) you will find the same prompt used in the snippet above [search `"Print out string (useful for prompts)"` within the page]

The table in the same section will explain you the meaning of the `li $v0, 4` and `li $v0, 8` instructions. This is another [good read](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/mips.html). The same table will make you understand that before calling a print string you have to set one argument [`$a0`] while for the read string operation you will need two [`$a0` and `$a1`]

In your code the main begins with a read string operation. But please notice that `string_space` is used both to allocate the size of the buffer where to read from [in `.data` section] and for asking to enter the word [you are trying to call `string_space: .asciiz "Enter your word:\n"`]. This issue has been fixed by the snippets above

In case of troubles don't forget to double check the content of your `string_space` buffer:

```
la $a0, string_space  # move buffer into a0
li $v0, 4             # print buffer
syscall
```

---

Complete code tested and working in MARS 4.5:

```
.data
string_space: .space 1024

input:  .asciiz "Enter a string: "
is_palin_msg: .asciiz "The string is a palindrome.\n"
not_palin_msg: .asciiz "The string is not a palindrome.\n"

.text
main: 

li $v0, 4              # system call code for print_str
la $a0, input          # address of string to print
syscall                # print the input

la $a0, string_space
li $a1, 1024
li $v0, 8
syscall

#la $a0, string_space  # move buffer into a0
#li $v0, 4             # print buffer
#syscall

la $t1, string_space
la $t2, string_space

length_loop:
lb $t3, ($t2)
beqz $t3, end_length_loop
addu $t2, $t2, 1 
b length_loop

end_length_loop:
subu $t2, $t2, 2

test_loop:
bge $t1, $t2, is_palin

lb $t3, ($t1)
lb $t4, ($t2)
bne $t3, $t4, not_palin

addu $t1, $t1, 1
subu $t2, $t2, 1
b test_loop

is_palin: 
la $a0, is_palin_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall
b exit

not_palin:
la $a0, not_palin_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall
b exit

exit: 
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

[image: MARS 4.5 output]

**IMPORTANT: this code logic has a bug. If you enter palindromes whose length is odd it will give the wrong result [e.g. civic is detected as a non-palindrome but actually it is]**

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I did have a .data and .text separation in the code I listed above.
Is that along the right lines?

Comment: @Jonathan you are right... I scrolled down the code, started searching for the links provided and when typing the answer the visible code was beginning exactly from length_loop... check it out now and good luck!

Comment: Thanks! After all of that, I'm getting another type of error:
Error in /Users/jonathanlin/Downloads/HW3Problem4.asm line 19: Runtime exception at 0x00400024: address out of range 0x00000000

Regarding the lb $t3, ($t2). Would you have any idea what this error entails?

Comment: @Jonathan I pasted the entire code that is working in MARS 4.5 [screenshot attached]. If you have other errors please don't use this question [which is about "I'm wondering how I can implement this so that it takes an actual word to test"] but please open a new one. Have a good day!